# Password checking security and link time optimizations

Tags: c, security, optimization

I have an application where I need to check whether a given input matches a stored password.

This is a simplified sample of the code:

```
int authorize_(const uint8_t input[restrict HASH_SIZE], const uint8_t password[restrict HASH_SIZE])
{
    // Compare each byte to prevent timing attacks. Make sure the compiler doesn't optimize the comparison.

    unsigned diff = 0;
    size_t index;

    for(index = 0; index < HASH_SIZE; ++index)
        diff += (input[index] != password[index]);

    return diff;
}

#define authorize(i, p) (bool)(authorize_((i), (p)) == 0)
```

I read about timing attacks and this is my solution: The function authorize_ always checks all characters to ensure that the check always takes equal time. Since external functions only care whether the result is 0 or not, I have a macro that does the check.

However I am worried whether the link time optimizations can cause the function to stop at the first mismatch (since diff is already != 0 and can only increase in value).

Should I be worried? Or am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: Is this a learning exercise, or is there another reason not to use a proven mechanism like BCrypt?

Comment: Compile the code in optimized mode, put a breakpoint and have a look at stop condition of your loop in assembler code.

Comment: Interesting... I'd like to know the answer too. I would assume that even if the current version can be optimised away (it would have to be inlined too, since "== 0" happens outside of the function), adding "volatile" to diff should prevent any compiler shortcuts.

Comment: I don't know about compiler optimizations, but I'd be inclined to replace `diff += (input[index] != password[index])` with `diff |= (input[index] ^ password[index])` to eliminate the branch that `!=` might create and ensure that `diff` can _never_ overflow.

Comment: @WeaponsGrade We try to minimize external library usage since the code is supposed to work on multiple platforms (including some embedded). On the side it's also a learning excercise. :)